# How do I load properties from application file for Testcontainer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, testcontainers

Currently, I am using Testcontainer to implement integration testing for database in spring boot. How do I init the Testcontainer with the application.yml. I don't want to use @DynamicPropertySource.

```java
public static PostgreSQLContainer container = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12")
```

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: user
    password: password
```

Comment: Why you don’t want to use DynamicPropertySource? Just to make it more challenging?

Comment: I just want use one application.yml for every test class

Comment: You can override application.yaml with application-test.yaml and define variables but still you need to use DynamicPropertySource to override yaml values in application-test.yaml.

Comment: That would be a very uncommon approach and I don’t get the advantage of doing so. Typically you would use profiles for test setups and override only small parts of the config using test properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add tc to you spring.datasource.url property.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:12:///db?TC_TMPFS=/testtmpfs:rw
    username: user
    password: password
```

I prefer not to use application.yaml just create application-test.yaml and override default one. You can check https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/.

Also you can override with @testpropertysource annotation.

Comment: it have error like this:  Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///db

Comment: Can you change the version ? posgresql:version

Comment: For Spring Boot (Before version 2.3.0) you need to specify the driver manually spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver

Comment: @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer container = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12")
            .withDatabaseName("db")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("password");

Comment: spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:12:///db
    username: user
    password: password

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: I changed driverClassName to org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver